# Jenkins integration test different environments

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a project that need to works on windows\linux with those databases : oracle\sqlserver.
Our project is built by Maven.

I have installed Jenkins with master\slave set-up.

master: windows + sqlserver

slave : linux + oracle

for our testing.

[Jenkins - Promoting a build to different environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772646/jenkins-promoting-a-build-to-different-environments)

but its really not helping that much for me.

I have also read Jenkins wiki : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds

but i still cannot figure out how should i do it.

Since compiling our code takes a lot of time i would like to ***do it just once*** than use the final result and test it on those environments master and slave.
build **succes** only if he runs on both environments.

I have also noticed that i cannot invoke on "post steps" at jenkins to do it. i didn't find any plugin that can really help with deploying and testing on the slave.

I have read somewhere that maybe i should split it to 3 jobs and not to use one job.
first job compiles, and then other jobs are running integration test. 
you can look at  : http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/the-correct-way-to-use-integration-tests-in-your-build-process/

I hope you could advise to me how should i do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would split the build up as follows:

1. Job 1 compiles the code, runs unit tests and builds your deployable artifact (since you're using Maven, I assume you have a JAR or WAR file)
2. Job 2 deploys and runs the artifact - you could use [build parameters](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) to specify environment-specific criteria.
3. Job 3 runs the integration test and reports results.

Comment: I didn't got from your answer how many jobs should be and what each job should do. did you mean that
job 1- compile  and create artifact
job 2- deploy artifact to repository
job 3 - runs integration  on sqlserver+windows(master machine)
job 4 -runs integration test on oracle +linux(slave)

Comment: You could create 4 jobs as you suggest, but if the deployment and test run logic is similar for SQL Server and Oracle (e.g. just the host name to run the tests on is different) you could use a single job with parameters to denote the differences in the environments.