# Creating different profiles for dev, testing and production

Tags: jenkins, development-environment, production-environment, dev-to-production

I have configured Jenkins for my project. But its a snapshot version.
I want to create 3 different accounts for **DEVELOPMENT**, **TESTING** and **PRODUCTION**.

Kindly let me how to start about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried searching on search engine called Google? or even stackoverflow forums?

Comment: What do you mean by accounts? In Jenkins?

Comment: accounts as in different environments for dev, testing, production.

Comment: @Prashant - Obviously i wud have. Not getting answer upto the mark so asking. Its better to sit quite rathen than criticizing.

Comment: @Shwet - This is community to help. Not to spoon feed. You have not shared what you have tried so far. We are ready to help when you are stuck.. not to do your job/homework for you.

Comment: If same jenkins is to be used for multiple environments' deployment, we can create multiple jobs in jenkins which can be configured to function as per the environment. e.g. taking pull from specific branch.. running a specific script etc..

Comment: What are you trying? Deployment?

Comment: @Prashant - Thanks for the response. I tried few things. But yes i shud have mentioned that.

Comment: @CShulz - Actually, we have two cloud accounts - one for dev and one for prod. Multi-tenancy id is maintained and based on that corresponding schemas are selected from persistence-unit from persistence.xml.

I wish to know how shall I create build jobs to differentiate between dev and prod and correspondingly deploy to dev or prod environments.

Or you can say how to have achieve different environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope your application is using Maven as build tool as you had added that as a tag previously.

In maven, you should create profile corresponding to each environment. Based on profile, `persistence.xml` can be used. More help [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

In Jenkins, you can create multiple jobs and can pass command line arguments to it in jenkins configuration. Those arguments can be configured depending on the environment you are pointing to. More help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385410/jenkins-building-for-different-environments) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772646/jenkins-promoting-a-build-to-different-environments)

Try out these and should solve your problem.